# Laravel Lumen 7 Broadcasting Events with pusher not working

Tags: laravel, lumen, pusher, broadcasting

I am building a Microservice with Laravel Lumen. The Service should broadcast Events to the pusher socket server when an new Data is inserted in the DB. I installed https://packagist.org/packages/pusher/pusher-php-server
and also made an account on pusher and created an application. I configured everything in the lumen app, but nothing gets broadcasted. can someone help me?

- I have set up the pusher credentials in my .env file.
- i have created a new Event: [NewTemperature.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmDmb.png)
- i have made a config folder and added the pusher connection: [config/broadcasting.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myUIx.png)

what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

I thought in this two steps:

1. Register the BroadcastServiceProvider at bootstrap/app.php

```
    $app->register(BroadcastServiceProvider::class);
```

2. Configure broadcasting.php at bootstrap/app.php

```
    $app->configure('broadcasting');
```